# Can i install ubuntu touch in meizu mx4?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Can i install ubuntu on meizu mx4 android edition like ubuntu edition with iso recovery in this page " https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices "

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can. Ubuntu touch has just been launched for Meizu 4. I did it on a Nexus 4 with android previously installed. All you need is to follow

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

which is easy.

Don't forget the backup before installation.

Beware: Ubuntu touch not yet as developped as Android is !!

Nicolas

Comment: It is worth pointing out that while people have successfully flashed on there Android X4's there are big issues http://news.softpedia.com/news/buying-a-meizu-mx4-with-android-to-flash-ubuntu-is-not-a-good-idea-485495.shtml